# Can I keep thinking during meditation?

Tags: mental-health, meditation

I mean, will it be still useful or useful to any degree if I think while meditating? What if there's a conversation going around inside my head? Please answer it specifically in the context of mental health. You can assume both a single thought and multiple thoughts, but addressing them individually of course.

Comment: You should let the thoughts come and go, just be passive and let them settle. This is called [Mindful Meditation](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-courage-be-present/201001/how-practice-mindfulness-meditation)